# Evaluate $\int x^3 \sqrt{4-x^2} dx$

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

Evaluate $\int x^3 \sqrt{4-x^2} dx$

Is my solution correct? In the book, some other (final)solution is given.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Check your answer by differentiating it, to see if you get $x^3\sqrt{1-x^2}$.  Then you do not need to ask us whether it is correct.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Got it.